# Unable to pass data to AngularJS component directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm trying to create a component directive using AngularJS 1.5. I'm passing the $scope variable defined in the controller to the component directive. But it's not rendering.

Here is the component directive:

```
.component('myComp', {
   scope: {},
   bindToController: {
       info: '=info'
   },

   template: [

       '<table<tr>',
       '<td>{{ $ctrl.info }}</td>',
       '</tr>',
       '</tbody>',
       '</table>'
   ].join('')

});
```

Here is the view

```
<my-comp info="employee"></my-comp>
```

But nothing is displayed and no error in browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Things Have Changed -- Again

Components now ignore the `bindToController` property. Instead use `bindings`.

```
.component('myComp', {
   //scope: {},

   //obsolete
   //bindToController: {

   //Use instead
   bindings: {       
       info: '=info'
   },

   template: [

       '<table<tr>',
       '<td>{{ $ctrl.info }}</td>',
       '</tr>',
       '</tbody>',
       '</table>'
   ].join('')

});
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e09c624r/)

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Understanding Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
.component('myComp', {
 restrict: 'AE',
 scope: {info: '='},
 template: [

   '<table<tr>',
   '<td>{{ info }}</td>',
   '</tr>',
   '</tbody>',
   '</table>'
 ].join('')
});
```